# Merge objects from two 2d object arrays by shared id column value

Tags: php, arrays, object, merge, mapping

I want to merge two arrays with the same value -> `user_id` to one array.
You can see I have two arrays with different objects. I want merge them by `user_id` to one array with all objects.
For example:

```
$array1 = [
    $array[0]->leads = 5643;
    $array[0]->user_id= 15;  
    $array[0]->sales = 1433;

    $array[1]->leads = 3264;
    $array[1]->user_id= 9;  
    $array[1]->sales = 1254;        
];

$array2 = [
    $array[0]->user_id= 15;
    $array[0]->processing = 2300;
    $array[0]->deleted = 203;

    $array[1]->user_id= 9;
    $array[1]->processing = 103;
    $array[1]->deleted = 80;
];
```

The following array is the target.

```
$result = [
    $array[0]->user_id= 15;
    $array[0]->processing = 2300;
    $array[0]->leads = 5643;
    $array[0]->deleted = 203;
    $array[0]->sales = 1433;

    $array[1]->user_id= 9;
    $array[1]->processing = 103;
    $array[1]->leads = 3264;
    $array[1]->deleted = 80;
    $array[1]->sales = 1254;
];
```

Comment: do you want the to be done in the same array?

As what I can see is that the 0th index and 1st index gets mised and even all other 1st indexes move to the index 0

Comment: please check array unique http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302

Comment: It's simple, you can't use any direct PHP array functions, because you have removed `leads` and added `processing` and `deleted` with array key 0. So you need to write custom code.

Comment: @mark1505us if that is the goal then check my answer.

Comment: @mark1505us do you mean you need to join arrays with the same `user_id` value?

Comment: @ishegg yes, the user_id is the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate your array and build the combined array of objects using `user_id` as the key.

```
foreach ($array as $entry) {

    // if an entry for this user id hasn't been created in the result, add this object
    if (!isset($result[$entry->user_id])) {
        $result[$entry->user_id] = $entry;

    // otherwise, iterate this object and add the values of its keys to the existing entry
    } else {
        foreach ($entry as $key => $value) {
            $result[$entry->user_id]->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Given the additional info you just gave (two separate arrays) the solution is basically the same, just merge the two arrays together first.

```
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $entry) { ...
```

(Working example at https://3v4l.org/ccdQc)