# Merging two array with same values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, array-merge

I have two arrays.

Array 1

```
Array
( 
 [1] => 111,
 [id1] => 1, 
 [2] => 11231,
 [id2] => 2,
 [3] => 12311,
 [id3] => 3,
 [4] => 11981, 
 [id4] => 4,
 [5] => 11761, 
 [id5] => 5,
 [6] => 11561, 
 [id6] => 6
)

Array 2

Array
( 
 [1] => 2,
 [id1] => 1, 
 [2] => 2,
 [id2] => 2,
 [3] => 3,
 [id3] => 3,
 [4] => 4, 
 [id4] => 4,
 [5] => 4, 
 [id5] => 5,
 [6] => 6, 
 [id6] => 6
)
```

Id key is user id in both arrays
And numerical key in second array is manager id

I want to merge these two array in below format.

Merge array

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 1
        ),
Array
        (
            [0] => 11231
            [1] => 2
        ),
[3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12311
            [1] => 3
        ),
[4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11981
            [1] => 4
        ),
Array
        (
            [0] => 11761
            [1] => 5
        ),
[6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11561
            [1] => 6
        )

        )
```

Array inside array is the value of first array.
2,3,4,6 key is values from second array.
Those users who have same manager id will be merge in single array.

Comment: Did you find your answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449501/how-to-merge-arrays-in-php-with-a-same-value/46450295.  Or   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973915/php-merge-arrays-by-value

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt(code), you might be closer to a solution than you think! Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Array Walk Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

```
array_walk($array2, function($value,$key) use($array1,&$result){
    if(is_integer($key))
    $result[$value][]=[$array1[$key],$array1['id'.$key]];
});
```

output

```
array (size=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 111
          1 => int 1
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11231
          1 => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 12311
          1 => int 3
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11981
          1 => int 4
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11761
          1 => int 5
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11561
          1 => int 6
```